# .get() is not filtering specific css selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the callback of my `.get()`-request I want to filter the contents for two different elements. This is my Code:

```js
function loadPosts(url) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        data = $.parseHTML(data);

        nextPageUrl = $(data)
            .filter('#detailnav > .next > a')
            .attr('href');

        data = $(data)
            .filter('#content')
            .children();
        data.appendTo(container);

        […]

    }, 'html');
}
```

and the html:

```html
<section id="#content">
    […]
</section>
<section id="detailnav">
    <span class="prev">
        <a href="link.php">Link</a>
    </span>
    <span class="next">
        <a href="link.php">Link</a>
    </span>
</section>
```

The problem is that no `nextPageURL`gets returned, but `.get()` definitely got it.

The `.get()`-request works as expected, and the data seems to get parsed directly. The problem seems to be the CSS-selector for the `nextPageURL`, because this works fine:

```
nextPageUrl = $(data)
    .filter('#detailnav')
    .find('.prev > a')
    .attr('href');
```

Unfortunately the selector will be a variable at the end, so I have no control which selector will be there in the end.

Comment: What is your issue? I don't get it. Beware, you are appending content but IDs must be unique

Comment: Oh sorry, total forgotten to write it down … The problem is that no `nextPageURL`gets returned, but `.get()` definitely got it. I put it in the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using filter, use find. You just need to wrap the contents in a div so find will work.

```
var html = $("<div/>");
html.html(data);
nextPageUrl = html
            .find('#detailnav > .next > a')
            .attr('href');
```

Filter just limits the set, it does not look for the children elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use filter to navigate into the children of your element. So instead of :

```
 .filter('#detailnav > .next > a')
```

do :

```
 .filter('#detailnav')
 .find('> .next > a')
```

Comment: Yes, that is not working for me, because of the variable selector. But thanks for the clarification, that it is not possible to put specific CSS selectors in `.filter()`.

Comment: @Afterlame what do you mean *`variable selector`*?

Comment: I will get the selector through a variable in the final version. That means it could be `#first > second > third > .next` as well as `#next`. I have no control over that.